# Access and write data to an existing file in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I hava the following class which creates a .txt file
and writes data in this file.

```
package junitexport;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class ExecuteWithRunListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filename = "report.txt";
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
        fw.write("add a line");
        fw.close();
        JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
        runner.addListener(new ExecutionListener());
        runner.run(MyUnitTest.class);

    }
}
```

My question is how can I access the same file from another class.

```
    import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;
import junitexport.ExecuteWithRunListener;

public class ExecutionListener extends RunListener
{
    /*
     * Called when an atomic test is about to be started.
     */
    public void testStarted(Description dsc) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
              //I want to write additional data to the previous file here

    }


}
```

BR

Comment: You can access this file same way as you do in main

Comment: Just pass reference to your file to the ExecutionListener constructor

Comment: As long as you have the file name available in both contexts there is no issue. In your case you could pass the file name as a parameter in the constructor of ExecutionListener

Answer (score 1):

As it is a text file, you can use [`Files.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write%28java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29)

```
public void testStarted(Description dsc) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Files.write(
             Paths.get("report.txt"), 
             "the text you want to insert".getBytes(),
             StandardOpenOption.APPEND
    );
}
```

Comment: Since you are working with bytes here, wouldn't you be able to use `Files.write()` on every kind of file? Also, you might need to handle charsets.

Answer (score 0):

Use OO principles. Create a class to manage this functionality. Move your code from main into a public method and call this from both places.
Suggest a method to create the file and one to update the existing file

In your Unit Test source file, simple create a new instance of your newly created class and call the methods on this to test it.